# chrome kiosk mode in windows 10, proper way to close chrome

Tags: google-chrome

we have an C# backend that launches and integrates with a chrome webapp in kiosk mode.  we have a message that is executed from webapp that tells the backend to close chrome and show the backend ui (a service ui).

This works fine, but we are using Process.Kill to close chrome.  We've got other issues that we believe that may be related to left overs from the harsh closing of chrome.

What is the proper way to close chrome, once Kiosk mode has been entered?